# PostgresSQL date when students turn 21

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that stores student **ID numbers** and **dates of birth**.

However we want to have a view of the date of their 21st birthday or whether it was in the past.

So a student born on `1/05/1990` had his 21st birthday on `1/05/2011`. Similarly, we want e.g., a student born on `1/01/2000` will have her 21st birthday on `1/01/2021`.

Table that holds `studentId` and `studentdob = studentview`.

Thank you very much in advance

Xenu

Answer (score 0):

You can use interval:

`select '1990-05-01'::date + interval '21 years'`

Answer (score 0):

Select students ids and theirs 21 birtdays:

`SELECT studentid, studentdob + interval '21 years' as '21st_birthday' FROM studentview;`

Create view from this select:

`CRAETE VIEW viewname AS SELECT studentid, studentdob + interval '21 years' as '21st_birthday' FROM studentview;`